# How to Clear TexStudio Word Search History in a Windows Environment

Tags: texstudio, search

I would like to know if there is a simple way of clearing all the previous word and term searches from the ``Find'' box in Texstudio in a Windows environment.

Is there something equivalent to a ``Clear History'' button for this task?

If not, might someone spell out the simplest way to do this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The search history is stored in the file  `texstudio.ini`. In my case (win7) in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\TeXstudio`.

In line #300 (again my case) it is located

Search\Find%20History= `<list of last searched items>` separated by commas.

I will suggest making a copy of the archive (copy and paste in place, windows will add "copy" to the name) and using a text editor delete everything from the `=` sign until the end.

Perhaps, before you begin, you could add a search with a strange word like  "xyxasad" to help finding the right line  and its end.